# Udacity Deep Learning, Assignment 3, Part 3: Tensorflow dropout function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda

I am now on assignment 3 of the Udacity Deep Learning class. I have most of it completed and it's working but I noticed that problem 3, which is about using 'dropout' with tensorflow, seems to degrade my performance rather than improve it.

So I think I'm doing something wrong. I'll put my full code here. If someone can explain to me how to properly use dropout, I'd appreciate it. (Or confirm I'm using it correctly and it's just not helping in this case.). It drops accuracy from over 94% (without dropout) down to 91.5%. If you aren't using L2 regularization, the degradation is even larger.

```
def create_nn(dataset, weights_hidden, biases_hidden, weights_out, biases_out):
    # Original layer
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_hidden), biases_hidden)
    # Drop Out layer 1
    logits = tf.nn.dropout(logits, 0.5)
    # Hidden Relu layer
    logits = tf.nn.relu(logits)
    # Drop Out layer 2
    logits = tf.nn.dropout(logits, 0.5)
    # Output: Connect hidden layer to a node for each class
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(logits, weights_out), biases_out)
    return logits


# Create model
batch_size = 128
hidden_layer_size = 1024
beta = 1e-3

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
    # at run time with a training minibatch.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    # Variables.
    weights_hidden = tf.Variable(
        #tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_labels]))
        tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, hidden_layer_size]))
    #biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))
    biases_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer_size]))

    weights_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_size, num_labels]))
    biases_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))


    # Training computation.
    #logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_out) + biases_out
    logits = create_nn(tf_train_dataset, weights_hidden, biases_hidden, weights_out, biases_out)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))
    loss += beta * (tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_hidden) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_out))

    # Optimizer.
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    #valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_out) + biases_out)
    #test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_out) + biases_out)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_hidden) + biases_hidden), weights_out) + biases_out)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_hidden) + biases_hidden), weights_out) + biases_out)


num_steps = 10000

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    #offset = (step * batch_size) % (3*128 - batch_size)
    #print(offset)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if (step % 500 == 0):
      print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
      print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))

  print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to turn off dropout during inference. It may not be obvious at first, but the fact that dropout is hardcoded in the NN architecture means it will affect the test data during inference. You can avoid this by creating a placeholder `keep_prob`, rather than providing the value `0.5` directly. For example:

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
logits = tf.nn.dropout(logits, keep_prob)
```

To turn on dropout during training, set the `keep_prob` value to 0.5:

```
feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels, keep_prob: 0.5}
```

During inference/evaluation, you should be able to do something like this to set `keep_prob` to 1.0 in `eval`:

```
accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test_prediction, y_: test_labels, keep_prob: 1.0}
```

EDIT:

Since the issue does not seem to be that dropout is used at inference, the next culprit would be that the dropout is too high for this network size. You can potentially try decreasing the dropout to 20% (i.e. keep_prob=0.8), or increasing the size of the network to give the model an opportunity to learn the representations.

I actually gave it a try with your code, and I'm getting around ~93.5% with 20% dropout with this network size. I have added some additional resources below, including the original Dropout paper to help clarify the intuition behind it, and expands on more tips when using dropout such as increasing the learning rate.

References:

- [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros): has an example on the above (dropout on/off) using MNIST
- [Dropout Regularization in Deep Learning Models With Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-regularization-deep-learning-models-keras/)
- [Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf)

Comment: I think the reason I'm confused is because I have a valid_prediction and test_prediction that do NOT come out of the hardcoded NN architecture:

Comment: valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_hidden) + biases_hidden), weights_out) + biases_out)

Comment: test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_hidden) + biases_hidden), weights_out) + biases_out)

Comment: So when I'm getting a test or validation set prediction, there is no dropout. I was assuming that that would avoid needing to do this. I clearly am missing something.

Comment: You're right that there wouldn't be dropout in this case. I have edited my answer above with additional tips that I think may be useful. Mainly, playing around with the value of dropout as it may be too high for this network size, or potentially increasing the size of the network.

Answer (score 0):

2 things I think can cause the problem.

First of all I would not recommend using dropout in first layer (that too 50%, use lower, in range 10-25% if you have to)) as when you use such a high dropout even higher level features are not learnt and propagated to deeper layers. Also try a range of dropouts from 10% to 50% and see how accuracy changes. There is no way to know beforehand what value will work

Secondly, you do not usually use dropout at inference. To fix that pass in keep_prob parameter of dropout as a placeholder and set it to 1 when inferencing.

Also, if the accuracy values you state are training accuracy then there may not even be much of a problem in first place as dropout will usually decrease training accuracy by small amounts as you are not overfitting, its the test/validation accuracy that needs to be closely monitored

Comment: I was reporting Testing accuracy.

Comment: "Secondly, you do not usually use dropout at inference. To fix that pass in keep_prob parameter of dropout as a placeholder and set it to 1 when inferencing." I don't understand what you mean here. Could you clarify?

Comment: I think this might be the part I'm not doing right. I keep reading about this but it's not clear to me what it means. I don't have dropout at all in the Test and Validate evaluations as far as I can see.